# Showing $ \lim_{x\to\infty} (\log x)^{1/x}=1 $

Tags: limits, logarithms

> How to show
> $$ \lim_{x\to\infty} (\log x)^{1/x}=1 $$

Let $y=(\log x)^{1/x}$, taking log on both sides
$$\log y= (\log(\log x))/x$$

Is my doings correct so far? What's the correct answer for this?

> The book offers the following
>
> **Solution:** Let $y=(\log x)^{1/x}$
>
> Taking log on both sides we get
> $$
> \log y=\frac{\log x}{x}
> $$
> Taking $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}$ on both sides,
> \begin{align}
> \lim_{x\to\infty}\log y&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\Big(\frac{\log x}{x}\Big)\quad\Bigg[\text{ in }\frac{\infty}{\infty}\text{ form }\Bigg]\\
> &=\lim_{x\to\infty}\Big(\frac{1/x}{1}\Big)=0\,.
> \end{align}
> Now, $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\log y=0\quad\Longrightarrow\quad\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}y=e^0=1\,.$
>
> Thus $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(\log x)^{1/x}=1\,.$

Comment: Are you asking about $\log(x^{1/x})$ or $(\log x)^{1/x}$?

Comment: the solution in the book [picture attached in the question above] says not ig!

Comment: Which is completely wrong.

Comment: @KurtG. so can you help me with the answer plz

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Which book is that from?

Answer (score 2):

The solution in the book is wrong despite the fact that it leads to the correct limit. Congrats for finding the problem.

Their mistake is
$$
\log y=\color{red}{\frac{\log x}{x}}\,.
$$

The correct answer is:

$$\log y=\log((\log x)^{1/x})=\frac{\color{blue}{\log}\log x}{x}$$
which by l'Hospital converges to
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x\log x}=0\,.$$ Therefore the limit of $(\log x)^{1/x}$ is one.